# Tool for shimano bb-un26 Bottom Bracket

Tags: bottom-bracket

What tool do i need to dismount a shimano bb-un26 bottom bracket?

Will a Park Tool BBT-22 work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Park  BBT-22 should work, but if you don't already have one, you might find the **Shimano TL-UN74-S** cheaper.